# Static no Django

Tags: python, django, static

Galera,
Queria um conselho ou ajuda sobre os 'static' no 'Django', meus arquivos que estao na pasta 'Static" eles nao vem ser carregados apresentando os seguintes erros abaixo:

```
    System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
December 30, 2020 - 15:49:40
Django version 3.1.4, using settings 'core.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6889
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/plugins/plugins.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1689
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/bootstrap/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/site.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1650
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/active.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1662
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/jquery/jquery-2.2.4.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1713
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1713
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/img/core-img/pizza.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1692
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/static/img/bg-img/foto_receita.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1728
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/img/core-img/logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 1689
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/bootstrap/popper.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1704
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1713
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/plugins/plugins.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1689
[30/Dec/2020 15:49:47] "GET /static/js/active.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1662
```

---

Na minha pasta settings.py esta da seguinte maneira

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
]
```

e minha urls.py esta assim:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('receitas.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] #+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Alguem que ja passou por isso que possa dar uma luz ?

Answer (score 0):

Após fazer o deploy da aplicação, você precisa executar o comando:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Assim os dados da pasta static serão copiados nos lugares devidos (configurados em seu `settings.py`) .

Segue a referência do [collectstatic do django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/).

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito